# C++ float to string with specific length

Tags: c++

Here my problem: I want to write a float with max 2 decimal places into a string and print it without a couple of 0's behind the number.

The way I do it at the moment:

```
Values Material;          // Class 'Values', Object 'Material'
Material.Temp = 15.56;    // 'Temp' = float

string ss = to_string(Material.Temp);  // Conversion to string
const char* cNumber = ss.c_str();      // Conversion to const char
HPDF_Page_ShowText(page, cNumber);
```

That prints out: 15.56000000

`HPDF_Page_ShowText` is a command of the open source library libharu to create PDF-Documents. It expects `(page-object, *const char)`. That is the reason why the string has to be converted into a `const char*` first.

I really searched in the internet for similar problems, but found none that fit to mine.

Comment: Will `#include <iomanip>` be of use to you? You can use `setprecision(2)` and it should truncate the floating point number. Unless you really need it in a string format?

Answer (score 5):

Use a [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [std::setprecision()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) function in combination with the [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) stream manipulator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    float myfloat = 15.56f;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << myfloat;
    std::string s = ss.str();
    std::cout << s;
}
```

The `const char*` variable can be obtained via:

```
const char* c = s.c_str();
```

Update:
Prefer `std::ostringstream` since the stream is used only for the output.

Comment: Yes, that helped. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should use `std::ostringstream` instead.